# .net class or something useful that can help me create a system backup image file

Tags: c#, .net

I am almost done creating a program using visual c# to gather everything I need in preparation for a system backup image.

Now, First, I would like to know how to create an image file.

Secondly if someone knows how to use or call Windows 7 "Backup and Restore" functionality rather than creating it from scratch will be very much appreciated.

I try to go and search for creating an image backup BUT come out nothing since the search engine shows an **"image"** topic literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Backup and Restore can be invoked from the command line, so, failing all else [use this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Here's a command line invocation I use on a server of mine:

```
WBADMIN START BACKUP -backupTarget:\\leahyfs\J$\DCBackups\New1\ -allCritical -quiet
```

Comment: Im almost using the same backup strategy like yours BUT the only difference is I am using my own port number. Does this still works  with port?

Comment: What are you using your own port for?  This just stores it across the network using standard CIFS/SMB.  You could have the backup saved somewhere locally and then use C# to read the file, send it across the network, and then delete it, if need be.

Comment: Okay..I think now we are much different but your solution is very much appreciated. I am creating the backup image and save it directly to a network server NOT saving it locally then transfer them later.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing in the snippet I posted, I'm just using CIFS/SMB to get the file there.  What are you using?

Comment: I see. Thank you. I will try that right away. Im using Linux server: Samba

Comment: Oh..sorry I miss that part. I'm still not focusing on backup restoration. I'm still working on backup creation. Does your code snippet still works on this?

Comment: Yeah my code snippet creates a backup and saves it in \\leahyfs\J$\DCBackups\New1\.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.. I tried to use the code snippets but nothing happened. Even running it directly to my command. The execution is done but no image backup found. Im using win 7 and xp during the test

Comment: [Many useful resources on using WBADMIN are found linked to here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wbadmin).